# Android Mysql database php file location

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm currently trying to make an android project that connects to a MySQL database on a remote server. There are multiple sources online that provide php code for this however i'm slightly confused as to whether the php files are stored on the remote server or not. Could someone clear this up for me please.

Answer (score 0):

of course php files should be stored on a remote server,
You should make some sort of dispatcher (using php) that gets your requests,
and push / pull data to mysql by those requests.

using REST will be best in this kind of situation.

you'r android app should connect to that dispatcher using http-request.

hope this helps.